# Prevent page refresh with specific events

Tags: ajax, jsf, events

We are required to use Internet Explorer, and we are using Java 8, PrimeFaces 5.3, with Glassfish 4.x.  I have to write an interface that deals with live stream.  I have the stream working fine.

Unfortunately, the commands are sent via CGI over the network (we have no control over this).  I need to send the start command on mousedown, an send a stop command on mouseout or mouseup.  I have run into 2 problems.  I am using h:commandButton because p:commandButton does not support the mouse events I need.  I have done a lot of searching via Google, but I can't find any answers.  Here is an example of the code:

```
<h:commandButton id="right" value="▶">
    <f:ajax event="mousedown" listener="#{backingBean.menubar.processAction('right', event)}" render="@none" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem occurs when I add `event=""`.  If I leave out the `event=""`, the page doesn't refresh.  This is what I want.  I don't want the page to refresh at all.  If I add the `event=""`, the page refreshes no matter what I seem to try.

What are my options?  I should note that event is always null.  The method in the backing bean was originally an ActionListener.

Comment: Is there any further code you can provide? Possibly showing what you've tried, what error messages you receive, etc? This post does not provide much to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page refreshes because `<h:commandButton />` is designed to submit the enclosing form via *POST* by default and loading the outcome of *action* attribute (leaving *action* empty reloads the current page)

To prevent the button of submitting you can add the *type* attribute with value 
*button*.

```xml
<h:commandButton type="button" />
```

An option to get *mousedown* and *mouseout* events working with `<p:commandButton />` (which is designed to do an *AJAX* request by default instead of submitting via *POST* and only updating comoponents listed in the *update* property)  and to benefit from it's capabilities like styling, is in combination with `<p:remoteCommand />`.

```xml
<h:form>
  <p:commandButton
    value="click me"
    onmousedown="mousedown();"
    onmouseout="mouseout();"
  />
  <p:remoteCommand
    name="mousedown"
    actionListener="#{commandButtonView.onMousedown}"
  />
  <p:remoteCommand
    name="mouseout"
    actionListener="#{commandButtonView.onMouseout}"
  />
</h:form>
```

*commandButtonView* is the backing bean with appropriate action listener methods.

Comment: So far, this seems to have worked.  I haven't had time to check the second part of your answer out, but I am giving you credit anyways.  Thanks.